# Selenium throws IndexOutOfBoundsException while opening new tab

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium Java program throws  **IndexOutOfBoundsException** exception when  executed below code to open new tab in Chrome.

Java Code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/john/Desktop/chromedriver");
                    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    String baseUrl = "http://google";
                    driver.get(baseUrl);
                    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");

                    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles()); 
                    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); // switches to  new tab
                    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
```

Error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b) on port 48571
Only local connections are allowed.
May 12, 2017 12:54:14 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at test.SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:31)
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException occurs when you try to access an index that is not present in array; so you have to check if the new tab is present or not?

Comment: tabs.get(1) is a culprit? as the error log shows your list size is just 1.

Comment: what is the result of tabs .size()?

Comment: It was typo. Thanks for pointing out guys. Changed index from 1 to 0. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of `tabs` is 1. You try to access position `1`, while the highest possible is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

In the line  `driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));` you get that exception. It's happening because, you've no any other windows open other than the first one.